# Null pointer exception TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a HomePage. I am trying to test the title of the page in TestNG using test annotation. I am getting NullPointerException for testTitle().The url is opening.

```
public class HomePage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver= driver;
    }
}

public class HomePageTest {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void openBrowser(){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("URL to open");
    }

    @Test
    public void testTitle(){
        HomePage page = new HomePage(driver);
        Assert.assertEquals("actualTitle", driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to remove the redeclaration from the @Beforemethod for Webdriver.  Rest all is fine - no change required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `WebDriver` instance public and there is no need to create it's reference again in `openBrowser()` method. Use following code:

```
public class HomePageTest {
    public WebDriver driver; //driver instance is public

    @BeforeMethod
    public void openBrowser(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("URL to open");
    }

    @Test
    public void testTitle(){
        HomePage page = new HomePage(driver);
        Assert.assertEquals("actualTitle", driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: @TDMH, Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow..so did not know about accepting the answers.Now I have figured it out:-) Thanks for your prompt answer!!

Comment: semi-related, but ... I don't think it's a good idea to instantiate webDriver in every beforeMethod(). I'd at least do beforeClass() or even beforeSuite()

Answer (score 0):

Make driver a field in class, that way it will be initiate in openBrowser.